# Difference between an empty list and unbound variable in erlang?

Tags: erlang, tail-recursion

```
max([H|T]) -> max2(T, H).        %% find the maximum of a list
max2([], Max) -> Max;
max2([H|T], Max) when H > Max -> max2(T, H);
max2([_|T], Max) -> max2(T, Max).
```

If you look at the second and last line of the function,it is sort of confusing.
second line says : "if the head is empty list,return the tail".

last line says : "???".

If head is unbound,then What?

Essentially,what i am trying to figure out--is there a diff between an empty list and unbound variable,or are they same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The empty list `[]` will pattern match only on an empty list. An unbound `_` will match on anything. So, the 2nd line above, is saying, "we are done recursing through the list, so output `Max`".

The bottom 2 lines are:

`max2([H|T], Max) when H > Max -> max2(T, H);`

The above line says, "if head is greater than current max, make head the max and keep going"

`max2([_|T], Max) -> max2(T, Max).`

Then this line says, "else, head is less than current max, so keep going with the current max (we disregard head by using `_`)"

In erlang, overloaded functions are called in order from top to bottom.  So, if there is a pattern match on the functions towards the top, the functions towards the bottom will not be called.  It is kind of like a recursive `if...else if...else` structure.

Comment: is there a diff between an empty list and unbound variable,or they are the same?

Answer (score 2):

Second line actually says "if `tail` is empty list, ...", not the `head`, because you passed `tail` as first argument to `max2`.

Last line says that when next element from the list is not greater than current `max`, just ignore it and call `max2` with remaining list and current `max`.